# Division in Django Query

Tags: django, django-views

```
Model:

class Vote(models.Model):
    thumbs_up = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name='thumbs_up')
    thumbs_down = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name='thumbs_down')

View:

qs = Vote.objects.all()

percent_min = request.GET.get('min-rating')
percent_max = request.GET.get('max-rating')

qs = qs.annotate(percent=(Count('thumbs_up')/(Count('thumbs_down')+Count('thumbs_up')))
                         * 100).filter(percent__gte=percent_min)

qs = qs.annotate(percent=(Count('thumbs_up')/(Count('thumbs_down')+Count('thumbs_up')))
                         * 100).filter(percent__lte=percent_max)

I also tried this which also didn't work.

qs = qs.annotate(up=Count('thumbs_up', distinct=True), combined=Count('thumbs_up', distinct=True) +
                         Count('thumbs_down', distinct=True), result=(F('up')/F('combined'))*100).filter(result__gte=percent_min)
```

I'm attempting to filter by min and max percentages based on user votes (up and down) but I can't seem to get it to work properly.

Using the current code if I, for example, put a maximum percentage of 74% in then it filters out everything rated 100% and leaves the remaining. The opposite happens if I enter 74% as a minimum percentage, it filters everything except those rated 100%.

Currently no 0 rated entries as I have to tackle the divide by 0 issue next.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So I came up with this which seems to be working:

```
        qs = qs.annotate(meh=Count('thumbs_meh', distinct=True), up=Count('thumbs_up', distinct=True), combined=Count('thumbs_up', distinct=True) +
                     Count('thumbs_down', distinct=True) + Count('thumbs_meh', distinct=True), result=Case(When(combined=0, then=0), default=((F('up')+(F('meh')/2))/(1.0*F('combined')))*100)).filter(result__gte=rating_min)
```

I added another model field for 'meh' votes hence the addition to the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to

```py
Vote.objects.filter(percentage__range=(min_perct, max_perct))
```

Although you need to generate a separate field for this method to work. Try adding:

```py
class Vote
    # ...
    percentage = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)


# Remember to update this field after every update!
v = Vote()
v.percentage = (thumbs_up/(thumbs_up + thumbs_down))
```